# Remove question mark from url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, friendly-url

I want to redirect the url : https://WEB_URL/video?id=1 to https://WEB_URL/video/1
and I have written following htaccess code but it is not working :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^video/([^.]*)$ video?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My full htaccess code is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /login.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # To externally redirect /dir/abc.php to /dir/abc
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^video/([^.]*)$ video?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

why it is not working ? What I am doing wrong please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /login.php

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /video(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /video/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/abc.php to /dir/abc
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^video/([^.]+?)/?$ video.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried your code but it redirect but showing page not found page

Comment: URL is `https://WEB_URL/video?id=1` and it redirects to `https://WEB_URL/video/1` but due to the htaccess code `ErrorDocument 404 /login.php` it showing login page. .htaccess code is in root

Comment: please look into my full htaccess code in my question